# How to change firebase config for deployed app

Tags: firebase, electron

I have an Electron App that I want to deploy for companies.  Right now I have hardcoded firebase config into the app. But after deploying if say 10 companies wanted to use my app with their own firebase config, how can I incorporate such thing into my app that lets companies configure their own firebase?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible without the code you need then e g 10 different firebase account to call 10 different databases and configs

Comment: I didnt understand you.